# Move column data based on last column

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I need to be able to move data from a group of columns (A,B,C) based on there being data in a fourth column (D) to a new group of columns (E,F,G).

```
A    B    C    D    E    F    G

20   0    0    15   15   0    0
0    10   0    5    0    5    0
0    0    90   90   0    0    90
0    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

When columns A, B and C are reported to have data and column D has data transfer the data from D to a corresponding column for A, B and C to be represented in columns E, F and G.

Comment: You said "move data" and "transfer the data". Does this mean you want columns A, B & C values to be cleared after the data is transferred to E, F & G? Or do the original values stay? This will make a big difference how the question is answered.

Answer (score 0):

An if statement might work.

in column E:
`=if($D1=requiredvalue,$A1,0)`

You didn't mention what the required value was to find in column D. If you mean a value above zero use `$D1>0`. If you mean one particular value use what I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, use the following formula:

- E: `=IF(AND($D1 > 0; $A1 > 0); $D1; 0)`
- F: `=IF(AND($D1 > 0; $B1 > 0); $D1; 0)`
- G: `=IF(AND($D1 > 0; $C1 > 0); $D1; 0)`

Expand the formula from the first row to rows below.

The third argument to `IF` is the value of the cell in case where the condition is false. It could be any number or the value of a cell, for example $A1.

Comment: Well, you can simplify that a little, to `E1` = `=IF($A1>0, $D1, 0)`.  And, if you leave out the first `$` and say `=IF(A1>0, $D1, 0)`, you can just drag it out to columns `F` and `G`.